# Question regarding Sum of squares in modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Based on my previous question which turned out to be regarding modular arithmetic, I have another question: I have two functions $$f_1=\sqrt{\left(\frac{19(8m-1)+1}{3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{22(8m-1)+1}{3}\right)^2}$$ and $$f_2=\sqrt{\left(\frac{19(8m+1)+1}{3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{22(8m+1)+1}{3}\right)^2}$$ Using modular arithmetic, $f_1^2$ and $f_2$ can be reduced to $4m_1^2+4m_2^2$ and $4(m_1+1)^2+4(m_2+1)^2$ (for some $m_1$ and $m_2$) respectively and therefore $f_1$ and $f_2$ will always be even. Is my reasoning correct? If not, can someone please point out where I am wrong?

Comment: Which modulus was used ?

Comment: modulo 3 which is the denominator of the fractions

Comment: What's 4 mod 3 ?

Comment: 4 mod 3 is 1. Why do you ask?

Comment: Aka it reduces to $$(m_2+1)^2+(m_1+1)^2 \bmod 3$$ for the second and $$m_1^2+m_2^2\bmod 3$$ for the first, even/odd is mod 2.

Comment: Did our chat help ?

Comment: Indeed.. Thank you so much.. Much Appreciations! :-)